# ECLIPSE : Error: Main method not found in class apple, please define the main method as: public static void main(String[] args)

Tags: java, eclipse

I am beginner to java. This code is working absolutely fine in command prompt but here in eclipse it is not running !

```
class apple{
    public static void main (String[] args){
       System.out.println("Hello , World") ;
    }
}
```

Comment: No , I am learning java through youtube.

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar - I understand , I just asked..

Comment: This code should run properly in Eclipse too! verify if your eclipse is having valid JRE configured

Comment: @Tsung-TingKuo - Check the title of the question :)

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar Oh thanks a lot :-P

Comment: Maybe @VivekSingh is right, it runs perfectly in my Eclipse...

Comment: @VivekSingh can you elaborate me regarding JRE configuration ? I mean how to correct it , since it is running on other people's eclipse ?

Comment: Which eclipse version are you using? Are you running the class from the package explorer's context menu (selecting the .java file, right mouse button => `Run as ...` => `Java Application`?

Comment: press alt+shift+x   then press j

Comment: Go to properties of your project (Alt+Enter)>BuildPath>Check Libraries>(Should contain a valid JRE), Then go to Java Compiler>and see if the jdk compliance is matching as that of the library present in the BuildPath

Answer (score 2):

You need to select your Java Application to be run: 
Right-click on your project root directory, Run As > Run Configurations.

On the left-side select Java Application, if there is a Configuration under 'Java Application', then select it, if not create it. Then under the 'Main' tab, select search and find the Main class in your project.

Then select Run.

Other reasons why it could be failing:

- Project was not saved before running.
- Eclipse glitch, try to restart.

Comment: Thank you so much ! Now it is working ;) By the way do i have to do this everytime for future java codes ?

Comment: Okay, I am really sorry ! The problem occurred because I didn't save my code before running.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happens, when ever some jar file is missing in build path.

This can shown clearly in problems window in eclipse.