# Main method not found error despite it being there (possibly error with selenium)

Tags: java, eclipse

This is code that has previously worked prior to my laptop hard drive failing.  I backed up the Java code in notepad and got the faulty drive replaced.  After which I re-downloaded both eclipse oxygen and selenium jars and pasted the Java code saved in notepad in eclipse oxygen.  Despite that I am still getting errors. I don't think it is because of that but selenium or eclipse.

## The error I have received

```
Error: Main method not found in class YTOW, please define the main method as:  
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

## Solutions I have tried

1. I have the main method in the same format as the error describes it.  I even removed the main method with the existing code and replaced with a simple:

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println("Hello World!");
   }
   ```

   yet I keep getting the same error.
2. Maybe it is an eclipse problem: I have restarted eclipse oxygen, restarted my computer, downloaded eclipse mars and tried it there, restarted eclipse mars and restarted my computer again but none of those worked.
3. Maybe it is a problem with selenium or Google WebDriver: Removed the previous jars and tested older versions of both.  Didn't work.
4. Maybe it is the way I configure the build path.  The way I did it is right click on the Java Project that I am working on -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path then I tried Adding External JARs with Modulepath selected which didn't work and then I tried Adding External JARs with Classpath selected which also didn't work.  I am not sure what to do.

I have been working on this problem for quite a long time and any of your help is greatly appreciated.

P.S.  The fact chrome web driver is .exe and not .jar has nothing to do with this right?  How would I even test that?  Again thanks for your help.

Comment: maybe this can help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34013755/eclipse-error-main-method-not-found-in-class-apple-please-define-the-main-me?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's saying "Main method not found in class YTOW" instead of "Could not find or load main class" suggests that it is finding a class YTOW without a main method, not that it's failing to find the class.

I'd check if you have multiple classes called YTOW in your classpath, possibly in different packages, and that the one you're trying to use is the one that has that main method you defined.

E.g. maybe there is a class YTOW in the base package, but you actually defined your main method in com.some.package.YTOW, or maybe there's a class YTOW defined in multiple jars and java is finding one you didn't mean to use.

Answer (score 0):

> previously worked prior to my laptop hard drive failing. I backed up the Java code in notepad

First off, I would strongly encourage you to *never* use Notepad. It's a surprisingly poor text editor and does a number of strange and undesirable things to your data. I would not be surprised if that was part of the issue.

Given that your hard drive failed it's possible (even likely) that your backups are corrupted in some way, preventing things from running as expected. Notepad could well be hiding (but not fixing) that corruption so it's not visible. Or the corruption could be elsewhere in the stack, e.g. Eclipse or your Jars.

I would suggest trying to build up from zero, rather than working down, so that you can build up the set of things you're confident are working as expected.

1. (Optional) Compile and run a simple hello world script with the `javac` and `java` command line tools
2. Compile and run a simple hello world script in a *fresh* Eclipse project, or even a new workspace, with a new installation of Eclipse
3. Link in the Jars you need, verify that the hello world script still runs
4. Pull in your project's source, verify the hello world script still runs
5. Move the hello world script into your project's main class (what you did in your #1 above) and verify it still works
6. Swap in your project's main method
7. Open your old Eclipse project in the new Eclipse installation
8. Open the new Eclipse project in the old Eclipse installation

Also, you should be using a proper version control tool such as Git or Mercurial to back up your code. That will give you confidence your project is not corrupted.